# Windows Proc "Unavailable" for processes spawned by service

Tags: windows-services, psexec, wndproc, windows-messages, spy++

I'm attempting to use `psexec` to spawn a process on a remote machine (for automated testing purposes) and noticed that the spawned process wasn't correctly responding to a message (`WM_GETOBJECT`, but that's another question entirely).  I opened `spy++` in an attempt to see why, but I couldn't log *any* messages going to my process' window.  The window properties also indicated that the "Windows Proc" for the window was "Unavailable":

[image: "Windows Proc" for the window is "Unavailable"].

I think this is a behavior of Windows services since `psexec` [uses an embedded service on the remote machine to launch the requested application](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/remote-computing/psexec).  I was logged onto both machines with the same credentials so I don't believe it is a user security issue but rather a service-related behavior.

As a sanity check I wrote a quick standalone server and client to execute a program remotely and everything worked as expected: the Window Proc was no longer "unavailable" and I could spy on messages.

I used the normal Windows Calculator (`calc`) for all my tests, i.e.:

```
psexec.exe -i \\other-machine calc
```

**My question:** Can someone confirm, explain, and/or cite why I can't see message queues of processes spawned off services?  Also is there a workaround to this?  I'd rather use `psexec` than my custom solution.  Bonus if you can also explain why `WM_GETOBJECT` doesn't return my custom UI Automation provider in this situation as well, as that's my original problem.

Comment: Since psexec uses a Windows Service to launch the executable, you might be running into [Session 0 Isolation](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSession0Isolation). Is your application started in Session 0? Maybe Spy++ has trouble accessing it.

Comment: I'm running on XP so I don't believe that's an issue for me.  To check anyways, I enabled the "Session ID" column in Task Manager and it showed "0" for calc.  However all other applications/services for SYSTEM or my user login are in session 0 as well.